# Running a local server with node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, localserver

I'm trying to set up a local server with node using this [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server) as a guide.

After pasting the first line into the terminal I get the following

[image] Any idea on how to get past this?

Comment: Would you tell us which line you _pasted_ into your terminal? I'm not sure if this is really on topic since it doesn't seem to be programming related... Did you try to do what ethe error suggests?

Comment: Without showing us the code you're trying to run, this question is both off-topic and unclear what you're asking.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment and for clarity I'm pasting the line 'npm install -g http-server' from the link referenced.

Answer (score 0):

This is typical when starting with `node` and `npm`. I see you're on a Mac like me, you could use something like `nvm` (Node version manager) to avoid installing node and npm in `/usr/local/xxxx`, with the added bonus of having multiple versions on your machine you can switch to whenever you want.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

You have other options to fix these issues, check out the official NPM guide here with the following workarounds:

1. Change the permission to npm's default directory.
2. Change npm's default directory to another directory.
3. Install node with a package manager that takes care of this for you.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Okay the reson is you forgot to use `sudo` in `npm`. This is a very common problem and not the right way to use nodejs. Here is a short version on how you can install node without the need to administrative priveledges. First use `NVM` or ode version manager.

### Install

Installation is as simple as

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
nvm install node
nvm use node
```

The benifit of this method is that you can manage multiple versions on node also. The above will install latest stable version. Once you are done with this, validate if `node` and `npm` are installed.

After that you don't need to add `sudo` before any global `npm` packages as it will install packages to your home directory and add that variable to `$PATH`.